# angular2-markdown module fails

Tags: angular, npm, markdown

I am trying to create a markdown editor in a form in my angular2 project and in order to do that I installed the angular2-markdown module in my project.
Unfortunately, when I'm trying to use it, I have this error : " marked " is not a function . The error comes from those lines :

> // comple markdown to html
>
> public compile(data: string) {
>
> return marked(data);
>
> }

Do you have any idea what can I do to fix the issue ?

That's the way I create my markdown input in my component :

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="textData" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</textarea>
<markdown [data]="textData">
```

Comment: Did you create the compile function or is it from the angular2-markdown module?  If you created it, make sure that the module you defined the marked function in, is imported into the module that contains the compile function.  If it is part angular2-markdown, then make sure it is installed properly with all of its dependencies.

Comment: I have a problem with the PATH of my project so I just c/p the markdown module manually. I think the module that imports the marked function is correctly imported because I have no error when I am doing " import * as marked from '../../node_modules/marked/index'; "

Comment: If I try to do a console.log to show the marked variable I have an object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the markdown but below suggestion is for general angular, typescript and developing angular components.

```
<markdown [data]="textData">  --> markdown is a component selector and not a function/method in a class

return marked(data);  --> marked() is called so its expected some where its defined. so if you are expecting to be available some here in markdown library, create an object of it and then use it.

const myMarkLib = new MarkLib();
markLib.markdown();
```